# how to use html to style a vb.net desktop application?

Tags: html, css, vb.net, user-interface, desktop-application

I'm not trying to do ASP.NET using VB.NET applications on the desktop. I want to create a desktop application that the user can enter information and retrieve information form a interface that is styled by html, css and java script. I'm NOT trying to interact with a web page at all, i simply want to make the desktop app look and act like a web app because a similar application will be available on the web this will just be like an offline version of it.

Comment: What do you consider to be the difference between a "web page" and "a interface that is styled by html, css and java script?"

Comment: @ckittel - I can't say for sure, but I would imagine it would be whether a server or desktop app/process accepts the request from the webpage.

Comment: if its a desktop application, and specifically a vb.net form it should be real easy to move around your controls and make it look the same as your html page since you do not have to deal with how the browser renders the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d67hf8a.aspx) control and set it's [DocumentText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext.aspx) property to the source code of a web page or set it's [DocumentStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentstream.aspx) to an IOStream of a local copy of your website. You can also use the [ObjectForScripting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting.aspx) property to exchange data between the vb.net application an the web page.

Comment: Thank you, this gives me something to start with.